# Android Studio Gradle error: 'android-maven' not found

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle

I'd like to add [CircularReveal](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) library to my app. I have copied circualreveal folder to .../MyApplication/libs/.
This is my settings.gradle file

```
include ':app', ':libs:circualreveal'
```

But when I try to sync project with gradle files there is an error

```
\AndroidstudioProjects\MyApplication\libs\circualreveal\build.gradle
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'android-maven' not found.
```

Here is \AndroidstudioProjects\MyApplication\libs\circualreveal\build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you downloaded library then delete " apply plugin: 'android-maven' "

Comment: Why not just add CircularReveal as a dependency in Gradle?

Comment: @IshRoid you can post your comment as answer.. Its work for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to add class path in your project build.gradle. It will look like this:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
  classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
}
```